# String not returning desired value

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE WCaresCheckContri    
    @PERNR bigint,    
    @RValue nvarchar(max) output    
AS    
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM WCARES_Check_Contri WHERE PERNR = @PERNR)    
    BEGIN
        SET @RValue = 'Y'   
    END
    ELSE
        SET @RValue = 'N'      

    RETURN @RValue 
END
```

C# code:

```
strRet = (string)objCmd.Parameters["@RValue"].Value;
```

This is my stored procedure. But it is always returning null value when I execute it from C# code. Any help welcome

Comment: What is the data type of the output param in your C# code?

Comment: string @Thangadurai

Comment: A return statement is not required in stored procedure

Comment: I still get a blank value. Something wrong with the C# code ?

Comment: @RichaSharma A small suggestion, when you using `IF EXISTS` you do not need to use `SELECT *` you can just use `SELECT 1`. ie. `IF EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM WCARES_Check_Contri WHERE PERNR=@PERNR)`. Improves your performance

Comment: If you're only returning a **single character** - ***why on earth*** are you using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` which allows up to **1 billion characters** ? A simple `NCHAR(1)` would suffice......

Comment: It anyhow doesnt solve the issue @marc_s

Answer (score 2):

Have you defined it as an output parameter?

```
objCmd.Parameters["@RValue"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
```

See [msdn article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/05/07/a-simple-example-on-how-to-get-return-and-out-parameter-values-using-ado-net/)

It would be helpful to see the surrounding calling code.

Try removing this line:

```
return @RValue
```

Comment: Yes, I did.. No success

Comment: Not able to execute the stored procedure also .. gives the same error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'N' to data type int."

Comment: @RichaSharma You should mention this error message in your question.

Comment: ' objCon.Open();
                SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("WCaresCheckContri", objCon);
                objCmd.CommandText = "WCaresCheckContri";
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("@PERNR", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empno;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("@RValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "";
                objCmd.Parameters["@RValue"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                strRet = objCmd.Parameters["@RValue"].Value.ToString(); ' code

Comment: You need to execute the stored procedure before you try to read the output parameter's value.

Comment: See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RichaSharma: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: I don't get the error if the return statement is commented in the stored procedure.

Comment: You can only return an int with a return statement in sql server.

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@RValue", SqlDbType.Text);
parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
objCmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
```